# Fill bar with gradient colors depending on the value

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am drawing a bar-chart. Each bar has the same color for the moment.

I would like to have a range of colors. For example the main color is `#00008b` and I will have different lighter colors.

The colors will depend on the value of my `y`

**CODE**

```
 svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "bar")
.selectAll("rect")
.data(fullData)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return xScale(d.year);
})
.attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.sale);
})
.attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
.attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - margins.bottom - yScale(d.sale);
})
.attr("fill", function(d){
    //code here
})
```

The idea is to get a code like the following :

```
.attr("fill", function(d){
    mainColor.lighter(d.value);
})
```

The smallest value would get the lightest blue and the biggest value would the darkest bar

Comment: Each bar is solid color?

Comment: Yep, each bar is one color. But the whole chart will be like a gradient color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, define your color scale:

```
var mycolor = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([10, 100])
    .range(["lightblue", "steelblue"]);
```

And use it according to the value:

```
.attr("fill", function(d){ return color(d)});
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var data = [40, 80, 50, 160, 230, 260, 10, 300, 140, 210];

var body = d3.select("body");
  
var divs = body.selectAll("div")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("div");
 
var color = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 300])
  .range(["powderblue", "midnightblue"]);
 
divs.style("width", function(d) { return d + "px"; })
  .attr("class", "divchart")
  .style("background-color", function(d){ return color(d)})
  .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

```css
.divchart {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is define a color scale

```
var colors = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, 200]) // you min/max y values
.range(['#000000','#ffffff']) // you min/max color values
```

and then call it like that :

```
.style('fill', function(d,i) {
    return colors(yScale(d.sale));
})
```

See the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6z7bgxam/